# Do I need to download Microsoft Internet Information Services?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, windows-xp

I'm not a hardcore programmer, but I did develop a company website using MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express and I want to keep working on it and I want to add things like a company Portal.  I use just a local desktop home computer (Windows XP Professional) and I just recently (thanks to good people here) moved to a webhosting company that has the ASP.NET 4.0 Framework on their servers.  Locally, when I want to view my website, I can see click "file" then "view in browser" and it points me to localhost.  Alternatively, I can upload it to my server's alternative FTP site where I can work on development.  I guess what I'm saying is that this computer isn't a server; it's just a desktop that I developed the site on.

I keep reading about Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS).  Do I need to download this onto my computer?  If so, [which IIS do I download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17275)?  What is it for, and how will it benefit me?  I also bookmarked the [MS Internet Information Services Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17275), but again, I don't know if it's worth my time to download this, or if it's pointless.

Any guidance in this regard would be extremely helpful.  Thanks!

- Jason Weber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be necessary to install IIS to work on an asp.net app. If you have your site in Visual Studio as a web application project rather than a web site project then when you run that project from VS then it will start from it's own built in web server. Thus a webserver such as IIS isn't a requirement for your dev work.

It's easy enough to put on IIS by following these other answers. That said, if it were me, the easy thing to do would be to have it as a web application project and run it from Visual Studio.

Comment: I think you're right, Tim ... for my purposes, I probably don't need IIS.  I have it saved as a web site, not a project, though.  It would be another story if I was hosting it myself, but if it's only for development, it could be a tool that's nice to use but not a prerequisite.  Thanks a lot Tim.

Answer (score 3):

IIS is the Microsoft Internet Information Services addin and it will be required if you are looking to host your own page from a desktop machine.  The most recent version available to XP would be advisable (not sure which one it is). It allows you to store your web documents in a folder on the local drive which can then be viewed in a web browser. You will also need to do some work with your broadband router, e.g. opening up port 80 and routing incoming traffic through to the IP address of your machine, you may also need to open port 80 in your firewall program. There's a little to much to go through on here but hopefully those points will take you inthe right direction.

Answer (score 2):

No you can install directly if you have xp cd. OR you have i386 folder in your pc(you should take backup before).

Follow these simple easy steps. http://chalaki.com/install-iis6-windows-xp-professional-sp3-setup-run-csharp-cgi/425/

Comment: Thank you Dinesh ... that's a good link and it's very simple to follow.  I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 1):

Start / Control Panel / Add/remove programs / Add/remove Windows Components.

In there you just check the IIS to be installed and Windows installs it from the installation location.

Answer (score 1):

IIS is part of operating system. You can not pick up version.

If IIS is not installed yet, from

control panel -> program files and properties ->  switch on/off windows properties

In case it is not in your list: you install it from Operation System CD or downloading is possible:
for example for Internet Information Services (IIS) 7 Manager
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2299

Comment: Great link Moguz -- I think the inetmgr_i386.msi would work, but I haven't decided whether to implement it or not yet.

Answer (score 1):

about what is iis i suggest you'll take a quick pick over here :

http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/definition/IIS

however about how to install it- it's quiet simple actually -

go to control panel->programs->under the headline "programs and features" choose -> "turn windows features on or off"

now you'll get a list of componnents , mark the following :
internet information services -> web mannegment tools -> mark the whole boxes of iis

click on ok and you are good to go.

Comment: That's a good informational link, Barak.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

As said before me VS Web Developer includes its own Development Web Server. So for development you don't need IIS. But after you finish developing you may need it for testing. So you need to do two things first install the IIS second Register ASP.net with the IIS.

Since you are using win XP operating system the installation is somewhat different from Vista and Win 7. Some steps suggested do not concern XP.
You should have the installation disk especially the service pack you used to install your XP.
Go to Control Panel>Add Windows Components >select Application Server , click Details button, Select Internet Information Services >Ok

AFter installing the IIS, you need to register(install) asp.net
right click on prompt command > Run as administrator > type this command and hit enter

```
cd c:/windows/microsoft.net/framework/v4.0.30319 aspnet_regiis -i
```

(if your operating system is 64 please replace the folder famework with framework64 and C: drive with your windows installed drive. For asp.net versions before 4.0 replace the last (v4.0.30319) folder with v2.0.50727).
IIS stores websites under the drive/inetpub/wwwroot
 To understand more google more

Answer (score 0):

Control panel -> Programs -> program and feature tab -> Turn Windows features on or off
-> in Windows features window -> Check parent option Internet Information Service and check child option Web Managment Tool & World wide Web Service